# How to tell beginning of file in python?

Tags: python, read-write

Currently I read a number of text files like so and write some csv lines using `fileinput`:

```
out_file= open( 'f.csv', 'wb' )
csv_w = csv.writer( out_file, delimiter="\t", encoding='utf-8'  )
os.chdir(sys.argv[1])
for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob("*.txt")):
    csv_w.writerow('something')
```

This works fine, but I want to write to separate output files.  Currently the loop reads through a file, then carries on to the next, just writing to one big csv file.

How can I tell that the current input file I am reading is now a different one (i.e. i have reached EOF of previous file and now am at BOF of new one)? I could store the filename and check it each time I read a new line but I imagine Python has some clever function up its sleeve. TIA!!

Comment: You can create new csv.writer (and new csv file respectively) for each input file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fileinput.filename`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.filename) to tell the name of the file currently being looped over:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import fileinput
import glob
for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob('*')):
  print(fileinput.filename())
's.txt'
't.txt'
```

This will fail if the "file" is in fact a directory. So in best IETAFFTFP manner:

```
import fileinput
import glob
for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob('*')):
  try:
      print(fileinput.filename())
  except IsADirectoryError as e:
      print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Is there any way to tell if it changes, other than  checking against the old value?